# Dynamically create an escaped constant (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need to dynamically create a constant that is escaped out of the current namespace, so I need the '::' in front of my constant.  However, when I try the below, I get the below error...

```
def make_constant(type)     
  "::"+"#{type}".singularize.camelize.constantize
end
```

When I try some thing like

`make_constant("MyModel")` the result should be a constant of:

```
::MyModel
```

However, I get and error:

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of Class into String)

Comment: I don't think their should be a "metaprogramming" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby `+` has lower priority than method invocation `.`, so you first create a class with `"#{type}".singularize.camelize.constantize` and then you try to add this class to  a string `'::'` that fails.

To fix it you can:

```
("::"+"#{type}".singularize.camelize).constantize # ugly, but proves the point
"::#{type.singularize.camelize}".constantize #elegant and working :)
```

Comment: The elegant option does not work because camelize does not operate the same way as the top version.

Comment: thanks @user2012677 fixed that by moving it inside the interpolation

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to concatenate or use parens on the method chain

```
def make_constant type
  "::#{type}".singularize.camelize.constantize
end
```

Comment: "::word".camelize = "::word", where "::"+'word'.camelize = ::Word